# Python: Count character in string which are following each other

Tags: python, string

I have a string in which I want to count the occurrences of `#` following each other to replace them by numbers to create a increment.

For example:

```
rawString = 'MyString1_test##_edit####'

for x in xrange(5):
    output = doConvertMyString(rawString)
    print output

MyString1_test01_edit0001
MyString1_test02_edit0002
MyString1_test03_edit0003
MyString1_test04_edit0004
MyString1_test05_edit0005
```

Assuming that the number of `#` is not fixed and that `rawString` is a user input containing only `string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '_' + '#`, how can I do that?

Here is my test so far:

```
rawString = 'MyString1_test##_edit####'
incrDatas = {}
key = '#'
counter = 1

for x in xrange(len(rawString)):
    if rawString[x] != key:
        counter = 1
        continue
    else:
        if x > 0:
            if rawString[x - 1] == key:
                counter += 1
            else:
                pass
                # ???
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: You haven't provided the detail of the `doConvertMyString` function, is that because you haven't tried to write it?

Comment: Is the `#` number dynamic or fixed? Can there be more than 2 chunks of `#` symbols?

Comment: Yes it's completely dynamic, in fact the `rawString` is a user input which can contain only `string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '_' + '#'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `zfill` in the `re.sub` replacement to pad any amount of `#` chunks. `#+` regex pattern matches 1 or more `#` symbols. The `m.group()` stands for the match the regex found, and thus, we replace all `#`s with the incremented `x` converted to string padded with the same amount of `0`s as there are `#` in the match.

```
import re
rawString = 'MyString1_test##_edit####'
for x in xrange(5):
    output = re.sub(r"#+", lambda m: str(x+1).zfill(len(m.group())),  rawString)
    print output
```

Result of [the demo](https://ideone.com/2boJvI):

```
MyString1_test01_edit0001
MyString1_test02_edit0002
MyString1_test03_edit0003
MyString1_test04_edit0004
MyString1_test05_edit0005
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below converts the `rawString` to a format string, using `groupby` in a list comprehension to find groups of hashes. Each run of hashes is converted into a format directive to print a zero-padded integer of the appropriate width, runs of non-hashes are simply joined back together.

This code works on Python 2.6 and later.

```
from itertools import groupby

def convert(template):
    return ''.join(['{{x:0{0}d}}'.format(len(list(g))) if k else ''.join(g)
        for k, g in groupby(template, lambda c: c == '#')])

rawString = 'MyString1_test##_edit####'
fmt = convert(rawString)
print(repr(fmt))

for x in range(5):
    print(fmt.format(x=x))
```

**output**

```
'MyString1_test{x:02d}_edit{x:04d}'
MyString1_test00_edit0000
MyString1_test01_edit0001
MyString1_test02_edit0002
MyString1_test03_edit0003
MyString1_test04_edit0004
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this-

```
rawString = 'MyString1_test##_edit####'
splitString = rawString.split('_')

for i in xrange(10): # you may put any count
    print '%s_%s%02d_%s%04d' % (splitString[0], splitString[1][0:4], i, splitString[2][0:4], i, )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this naive (and probably not most efficient) solution. It assumes that the number of `'#'` is fixed.

```
rawString = 'MyString1_test##_edit####'

for i in range(1, 6):
    temp = rawString.replace('####', str(i).zfill(4)).replace('##', str(i).zfill(2))
    print(temp)

>> MyString1_test01_edit0001
   MyString1_test02_edit0002
   MyString1_test03_edit0003
   MyString1_test04_edit0004
   MyString1_test05_edit0005
```

Answer (score -2):

```
test_string = 'MyString1_test##_edit####'

def count_hash(raw_string):
    str_list = list(raw_string)
    hash_count = str_list.count("#") + 1
    for num in xrange(1, hash_count):
        new_string = raw_string.replace("####", "000" + str(num))
        new_string = new_string.replace("##", "0" + str(num))
        print new_string

count_hash(test_string)
```

It's a bit clunky, and only works for # counts of less than 10, but seems to do what you want.
EDIT: By "only works" I mean that you'll get extra characters with the fixed number of # symbols inserted

EDIT2: amended code

Comment: It doesn't actually. In the second iteration there are no `'#'` to replace.